# how to add costum ID in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe of covid information from different regions in UK.
I want to add a column and give every region an ID,( for example I want Scotland to be 1, Wales 2,...)
the data frame looks like:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Scotland | 1/2020 |
| Scotland | 2/2020 |
| Scotland | 3/2020 |
| Scotland | 4/2020 |
| Wales | 1/2020 |
| Wales | 2/2020 |
| Northern Ireland | 2/2020 |
| Northern Ireland | 3/2020 |
| ... | ... |

I have tried:

```py
UK_df['ID'] = 0
for index, region in enumerate (UK_regions):
    UK_df[UK_df.Name == region][x] = index
```

but it gave an error.
this is what I want:

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Scotland | 1/2020 |
| 1 | Scotland | 2/2020 |
| 1 | Scotland | 3/2020 |
| 1 | Scotland | 4/2020 |
| 2 | Wales | 1/2020 |
| 2 | Wales | 2/2020 |
| 3 | Northern Ireland | 2/2020 |
| 3 | Northern Ireland | 3/2020 |
| 4 | ... | ... |

Comment: `df.groupby('Name').cumcount()` ?

Comment: `df['ID'] = pd.factorize(df['Name'])[0] + 1`